# Please check my program and find out error

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make a simple action in which when i press a button then i should jump to another activity. But in this program whenever i press submit button an error is occurred and program terminated.

Please check my code and help me what error i have done.

**My first activity**

```
package login.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class login extends Activity  
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText e;
    Button b;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
       e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
        {
           if (v.getId() == R.id.submit) 
            {
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), some.class);
               startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            } 
            else
            {
                e.setText("cant go");
            }
       }
    });
    }
}
```

**second Activity**

```
package login.test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class some extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="saan"
    />

<Button android:text="Submit" android:id="@+id/submit" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText" android:id="@+id/editText1"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

**welcome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText android:text="You are welcome" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should provide the stack trace about your error as well, instead of making us guess what kind of exception causes your problem. Also, you could try changing `v.getContext()` to `login.this`.

Comment: What do you meen by stack trace ? please tell me...

Comment: The log part showing the error that occured. Also, please check @CapDroid's answers, and make sure you have all the necessary activities declared in your `androidManifest`.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed add your second activity in menifest..

So plz add second activity in menifest.

and second thing is no need to check

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.submit)
```

because you setOnClickListener on button so v will always button.

remove this condition

compare my code with your..

```
b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
        {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(login.this, some.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


       }
    });
```

Comment: Sir i have added my second activity in menifest. please suggest me another solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
{

@Override
   public void onClick(View v)
    {

```
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), some.class);
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

}
});

and also second activity class define in AndroidManifest.xml